# Could not find capistrano-2.11.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to use capistrano to handle deployment of my Rails 3.2.1 app.

I'm getting this error when I run `cap deploy:update`

```
Could not find capistrano-2.11.0 in any of the sources
```

I was having issues with capistrano-2.11.0, so I downgraded to 2.9.0.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'capistrano', '2.9.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

`bundle show capistrano`:

```
 /Users/Tyler/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/capistrano-2.9.0
```

Why is it looking for capistrano-2.11.0?

Capfile:

```
load 'deploy' if respond_to?(:namespace) # cap2 differentiator
#require 'deploy'
# Uncomment if you are using Rails' asset pipeline
 load 'deploy/assets'
Dir['vendor/gems/*/recipes/*.rb','vendor/plugins/*/recipes/*.rb'].each { |plugin| load(plugin) }
load 'config/deploy' # remove this line to skip loading any of the default tasks
```

config/deploy.rb

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
set :application, "CapistranoApp"
set :repository,  "ssh://ubuntu@ror.weaponxo.com/home/ubuntu/projectdir.git"
set :applicationdir, "/var/www/#{application}"
set :domain, "ror.weaponxo.com"
set :use_sudo, false
set :user, "ubuntu"
#set :default_environment, {'PATH' => "/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/:$PATH"}

 set :scm, :git
 set :branch, "master"
 set :git_shallow_clone, 1
 set :scm_verbose, true
 # Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

 role :web, domain                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
 role :app, domain                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
 role :db,  domain, :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run

 set :deploy_to, applicationdir
 set :deploy_via, :remote_cache

 $:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path'])) # Add RVM's lib directory to the load path.
 require "rvm/capistrano"                  # Load RVM's capistrano plugin.
 set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p290'        # Or whatever env you want it to run in.
 set :rvm_type, :user  # Copy the exact line. I really mean :user here

# if you're still using the script/reaper helper you will need
# these http://github.com/rails/irs_process_scripts

# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
 namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
     run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
   end
 end
```

I did run `gem install capistrano` initially, so is that version (2.11.0) tucked away somewhere?

Thanks

### Edit

Note, capistrano-2.9.0 is the only version installed, I previously ran `bundle uninstall capistrano` and removed 2.11.0.

I ran `bundle exec cap deploy:update` and still get the same error.

### Edit 2

I recommitted my Gemfile.lock file to the repo.  It reads capistrano 2.9.0.

### Edit 3

Running `cap deploy:cold` worked.

Comment: Which version of capistrano is in your `Gemfile.lock`?

Comment: @James - That might have been one issue.  I had no recommitted those changes.  I have since committed the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock (both say capistrano 2.9.0) to the repo.  Same result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capistrano 2.11.0 was yanked from the gems.  The new version is 2.11.1.

## Edit

2.11.1 was also yanked.  Currently on 2.11.2

Comment: This appears to be a fairly common thing as 2.13.3 was also yanked.

Comment: Now we're up to 2.15.4. See [Rubygems Capistrano](http://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano) for version information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bundle exec cap deploy` which will use the capistrano version specified in your Gemfile

Answer (score 1):

Either uninstall capistrano 2.11.0 or always use `bundle exec` when running gem specific commands so it uses the version specified in your gemfile.

`bundle exec cap deploy:update`